# set Google Apps SPF record in Amazon AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, g-suite, spf, amazon-route53

I'm using the new AWS GUI for Route 53 to setup my domain records. However, the AWS console won't accept the recommended Google Apps SPF record, `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` (found [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723)).

It keeps giving me an error stating

```
The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.
```

This happens when saving as SPF and TXT. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to quote it, which threw me off too. Google's instructions are **terrible**, which is why i wrote up a complete guide on this: https://blog.andrewray.me/setting-up-gsuite-gmail-custom-domains-with-aws-route53/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had to wrap my SPF record in quotation marks for it to work.

`"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"`

Answer (score 1):

It's a new feature for the console. Chances are it's the console part that is rejecting the 'invalid' characters, rather than the underlying system.

I'd try setting it with one of the [many tools available for configuring Route 53](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?WhereGoFromHere.html) and if that doesn't work, contact Amazon

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to wrap the record in quotation marks and replace the ~ with a -.

Here is the value that works:

"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com -all"

Comment: According to https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en you should use ~all not -all for Google Apps.

Comment: The only reason I replaced the ~ with - was to get Route 53 to accept it, but to my surprise, it was also accepted by Google Apps as valid.

Answer (score -1):

Using doubles you can set that value without raising error messages. It worked fine for me.

Comment: To clarify, he meant to say ""double quotes"", which bypasses the checks for invalid characters.